# Looking for an Online Card Shuffler and Drawer

Tags: 7-wonders, online

For some play-by-forum games I'm looking into creating specific card based games that allow people to moderate on their own.

Specifically I'm looking into 7 Wonders. The only thing a mod needs to do is distribute hands at the beginning of each Age (including Leaders). Once everyone has received his initial hand he can just pick a card and send the rest along to his neighbor. For this we've used a token (just post DONE after you've picked your card) after which you'll receive your next hand from your neighbor. Obviously this requires some trust that you've actually picked a card and not just posted that you've done this, but on our forum it hasn't been an issue.

This leaves me with shuffling and drawing cards. Is there any way (an online app maybe) to allow people to draw cards from the same deck without seeing the cards that have been drawn by the other players? The order that they draw cards in doesn't matter much as long as each player just gets a hand of 7 random cards and gets it only once.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could always just use a physical copy of the game, shuffle the cards, deal the appropriate number of hands, and then send a message to each player listing out one of the hands.

Comment: Well, that would always be an option, @bwarner, but I want some way to participate myself without being able to look at everyone's hands. :)

Answer (score 2):

The game [Tabletop Simulator](https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160) has many games on the workshop, including [7 Wonders](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=800202229).

Tabletop Simulator (TTS) is exactly what the name implies: it simulates a tabletop. You can play chess, checkers, poker, or any game really since the game has extensive support to import own games. Even more, there is a whole scripting environment to automate actions/mechanics in games.

One of the great features TTS has is that you can shuffle cards and deal to all players. You can simulate this for your forum group, but if you guys want to take it real time you can all acquire TTS and play together. Online.

This is why TTS is so popular. It allows players that normally don't have that much time to come together play awesome games. It is also used a lot for playtesting custom games, so if you're into that, you might want to check it out as well.